How to show or hide specific bricks using vertex colors?
Hey fellow Blender gurus!
A little bit of brain teaser here (or maybe not). I have two Brick Textures (of different color) and an unwrapped cube. What I want is use vertex painting to create some kind of a mask that allows showing or hiding a brick in case there is a painted vertex inside of it. So there should be some kind of filling, where the vertex color gets "propagated" over the entire brick. Please see the pictures attached. Is this even feasible to do?
I am new to Blender and I have no idea how to approach this tbh. Googling or ChatGPTing didn't help.
Thanks :)



tbh i think you are using the wrong tool to achieve your goal. Shaders are a "per point/pixel" thing and there is not a "kind of" attribute statistic node as in geometry nodes. So in my opinion a better chance to solve this would be animation nodes/geometry nodes. In GN you could rebuild the brick texture as geometry, use the attribute statistic node to decide, which instance to use and the two instances would have different colors.
